# (Java) Switch Cannot Find Symbol

Tags: java, class, switch-statement

I am getting an error with `cannot find symbol` with a switch. I've done switch before however, that was in the driver. This is my first time using a switch in my own class. Anyways here a sample of my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class TrumpWar
{

   protected CardPile pl;
   protected CardPile p2;
   protected CardPile tCard;
   protected CardPile treasury;

   public TrumpWar( )
   {
        CardPile cp = new CardPile (new Card [52]);
        cp.shuffle();

        CardPile tCard = new CardPile();
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
            tCard.get(i);
        cp.shuffle();

        CardPile p1 = new CardPile(new Card [26]);
        CardPile p2 = new CardPile(new Card [26]);
    }

public void play()
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    do
    {
        System.out.println("At each turn, type: ");
        System.out.println("P to print");
        System.out.println("M to mix (shuffle the cards)");
        System.out.println("S to save");
        System.out.println("Q to quit");
        System.out.println("just ENTER to play a turn");

        String meunChoice = kb.nextLine();

        if(!meunChoice.equals("M") || !meunChoice.equals("m") || !meunChoice.equals("P") || !meunChoice.equals("p") || !meunChoice.equals("Q") || !meunChoice.equals("q") || !meunChoice.equals("S") || !meunChoice.equals("s") || !meunChoice.equals(str = String.valueOf(kb.nextLine())))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Incorrect input, please re-enter.");
        else
        {
            switch (meunChoice)
            {
                case ("P"):
                case ("p"):     System.out.println("Player1 cards: " + p1.toString()); //<--- Cannot find p1.
                                System.out.println("Player1 cards: " + p2.toString());
//More codes...
```

I have no clue as to why I am getting that error when clearly I've declared p1 outside of the switch scope. Unless, there is a different way of using a switch in a class when compared to a driver.

Also, please ignore any logic errors as this is still a work in progress. I, at least, need the program to compile first before I can tackle any logic errors.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You might want to rename CardPile pl; to CardPile p1; and also do not re-declare them in constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute is named `pl`, *not* `p1`, and besides `p1` was declared in the `TrumpWar()` constructor as a local variable, clearly it can't be accessed from `play()`. What you have to do is this:

```
// outside

protected CardPile p1; // you wrote pl, rename it!

// in the constructor

p1 = new CardPile(new Card [26]);
p2 = new CardPile(new Card [26]);
```

*Now* the attributes `p1` and `p2` are being instantiated, in your code you were declaring a couple of local variables that happened to have (almost) the same name as the attributes - a compiler warning should have told you that.

Comment: And rename pl at the top of the class to p1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are shadowing the p1 and p2 variables, by re-declaring them in the constructor.

Instead of

```
 CardPile p1 = new CardPile(new Card [26]);
 CardPile p2 = new CardPile(new Card [26]);
```

Try doing

```
 p1 = new CardPile(new Card [26]);
 p2 = new CardPile(new Card [26]);
```

The difference is that in the first case you are declaring a variable (since it has the class type, i.e. CardPile) and in the second case you are using the variable already declared at the top, which is what you want to do apparently.

So if you re-define the variables p1 and p2 inside the constructor, they will remain undefined outside of it, i.e. inside play() p1 and p2 are null.